# How to make legend items bold in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I am able to bold the axis title and ticks using `update_xaxes`,but is there a way to do the same for the items in the legend?

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species",
                title="Automatic Labels Based on Data Frame Column Names")

fig.update_xaxes(tickprefix="<b>",ticksuffix ="</b><br>",title_text= "<b> sepal_length </b>" )
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done via the layout update API for legends at the moment since there doesn't appear to be an option you can leverage (https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend). If applicable, you could try change the font family to a bolder variant.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! i also looked around to see if there was an equivalent of  `update_xaxes` for adjusting legend, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda function and some basic html formatting with:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = '<b>' + t.name +'</b>'))
```

And get:

[image]

If you'd like to highlight one or *some* of the legend entries you can sprinkle the previous statement with:

```
bold = 'versicolor'
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = '<b>' + t.name +'</b>') if t.name in bold else())
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species",
                title="Automatic Labels Based on Data Frame Column Names")

# Plot 1
# fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = '<b>' + t.name +'</b>'))

# Plot 2
bold = 'versicolor'
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = '<b>' + t.name +'</b>') if t.name in bold else())

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if exists a way to make a entire legend (with values) bold, but you can set label with `labels` kwarg on `px.scatter` method, and then add some html  to make it bold.

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(
    df, 
    x="sepal_length", 
    y="sepal_width", 
    color="species",
    title="Automatic Labels Based on Data Frame Column Names",
    labels={
      "species": "<b>Species</b>" # here :)
    })

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `plotly.graph_objs`, add `<b>` `</b>` to trace 'name' :

Example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,name=f"<b>Text</b>"))
```